# How are all kinds of equilibra in game theory connected to each other? (Please correct my summary)

Tags: game-theory, bayesian, nash-equilibrium

I am a TA in a basic class on game theory in the economics department. I am ashamed to admit, but I do not entirely understand how all the different kinds of equilibria connected to each other. The class is taught in german, so I hope I am using the correct terms. I will now write down how I understand everything, and would kindly ask someone who knows more about the topic to correct me at appropriate points.

*Side note: When I say "more general", I mean that it is applicable to a wider range of problem, while when I say "stricter", I mean that it is applicable to the same kinds of problems, but puts more restrictions in place (, and eliminates some equilibria).*

#### The games:

There are games with **perfect** and **complete** information. There are also games with **imperfect** information, where one player is unsure about the decisions of other players at some point. There are also games with **incomplete** information, where some players are nor only in the dark about some other players action, but also about the types of other players.

Games can also be split in **simultaneous** and **sequential** games. The simultaneous games can be understood as a special simple case of the sequential games with imperfect information. (A special case of the simultaneous games are signalling games, but I don't think it is very relevant for my question.)

For simplicity sake, I limit myself to **one-shot** games, but I am pretty sure that all this works equally well for **(in)finitely repeated** games. *But this is really just an educated guess, math is weird, so there might be a top of exceptions.*

#### Now, how do we go about solving them:

The simplest option is the **Nash-Equilibrium (NE)** *in pure strategies*. "Each player picks an action." This one works really well for simultaneous games, but doesn't find all equilibria. This is mostly applied to simple simultaneous games, or simple sequential games.

An *extension* of the NE in pure strategies, is the **NE** *in mixed strategies*. "Each player picks a probability distribution over all his actions." (With probabilities of 1 and 0 we get the former case.) This method finds ALL equilibria, even this implausible ones. This is applied in pretty much the same cases as the former.

A *stricter* option, which only becomes relevant in sequential games with several subgames (if there is only one (sub)game this yields the same equilibria) is the **subgame perfect equilibrium**. It can be found through *backwards induction*. In comparison to the NE (in mixed strategies, because pure strategies are just a special case) it yields *less or the same number* of equilibria, eliminating the ones which are not subgame perfect. Those can be equilibria with the same equilibrium path, but irrational actions beside the path (and therefore irrelevant because of it) or equilibria with a different path, which are supported only through an incredible threat.

Now there are only two concepts known to me left, which need to be somehow tied into the picture. The **bayesian NE (BNE)** and the **perfect bayesian equilibrium (PBE)**. *I am not entirely sure about the next parts, so please look closely at them.*

The **BNE** is a *more general version* of the NE. It is required when we are dealing with games of incomplete information.

Here the players maximize their expected utility like in the NE with mixed strategies (and like they actually ALWAYS do), but they do it now not only with regard to the other players decision, but also with regard to natures "decisions"/other players types.

Thats about it. It is not really conceptually different, it is only that the expected utility has to be calculated with different typen in mind using the bayes rule for probabilities of actions. *The distribution of types is common knowledge.* The relationship between the NE and the BNE is as similar as the one between the pure and mixed strategy NE. A NE is a special case of the BNE where there is no "nature-move", because there are no different types of players. Therefore technically the BNE could be applied to all the simpler games, but we would not gain anything, as we ended up in the normal NE anyway.

The last concept, the **PBE**, is actually a *stricter* concept, than the BNE. It not only requires that players consider the probability of other players having different types, but also that the players *update their beliefs* wherever possible, using the *bayes rule*.

[Here is a little picture, of how I tried to put everything together.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6k7j.png)

Comment: I would think the best person to ask would be the person teaching the course.

Comment: That is actually a great suggestion ... I will try it again, but last time I tried, I couldn't persuade her that this is actually a problem worth thinking about. We do not really teach it like that in the course, so it is really only for my understanding, and she is quite busy, so I couldn't get a satisfactory answer. Thats why I now sat down and spent a day writing this. It helped me to understand to connections, and I hope it can help the others who are learning this - in case I am right of course :D

Comment: One way to look at is that some Nash equilibria look unintuitive, so people choose refinements, such as perfect equilibrium which get rid of the equilibria they don't think are reasonable.